# Does using strip remove the RTTI information on a binary?

Tags: c++, gcc, obfuscation, rtti, strip

When I compile a C++ binary using gcc with option to keep symbol information and when I run the following command it lists the typeinfo for the classes

```
objdump -Ct ExecName | grep typeinfo
```

When I compile with the stripped option -s and run the following it says no symbols.

But I am worried the RTTI information is being held in some other place.

I would prefer all the class names to be not shown in the binary. I would like a confirmation whether stripping symbols actually ends up removing the RTTI information.

In this presentation at Blackhat they show how to use RTTI to learn about the binary. 
http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-dc-07/Sabanal_Yason/Paper/bh-dc-07-Sabanal_Yason-WP.pdf

I know you could turn off RTTI by using -fno-rtti when compiling but I want this to be the last resort.

Comment: nope (padding padding padding)

Comment: You might check with the `strings` command line utility whether your binary contains your class names in plain text...

Comment: @pt123 The document you referenced talks about MSVC.  g++ is free to implement RTTI some different way.  The MSVC description includes class names, the g++ method may not.  You need to find out how g++ does RTTI.

Comment: Brian that's why I am asking here, I have searched the internet read many questions here on RTTI, the ones concerned with class names tend to be MSVC and not g++

Comment: @Arne you are right the Strings contained the class names with a number in front, I had missed them earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am worried the RTTI information is being held in some other
>   place.

It is.

When I ask the compiler to perform `dynamic_cast`, then it *must* honour the contract of `dynamic_cast`, and that requires RTTI. The only way to escape this is to have a compiler setting which would give an error or UB when you attempt to use `dynamic_cast` in this fashion. The compiler is *obliged* to provide RTTI by the language, unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.

Comment: according to this comment on another thread it can use a has ==> "this does not actually require storing the name, only an id. A hash, for example, would work too" 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948454/1527440

Comment: @pt123: The Itanium ABI forbids that, I'm pretty sure.